# Errors while interacting with microSD card?

Tags: arduino-esp32

I have an ESP32-CAM board with a microSD card attached (8GB). In my setup function I create a directory. In loop the ESP32-CAM takes images and stores in the directory.
The code successfully creates the directory and captures one image inside the directory. However, when the loop function runs the second time, I get the following errors:

```
E (8526) sdmmc_cmd: sdmmc_read_sectors_dma: sdmmc_send_cmd returned 0xffffffff
E (8531) diskio_sdmmc: sdmmc_read_blocks failed (-1)
E (9536) sdmmc_req: sdmmc_host_wait_for_event returned 0x107
E (9536) sdmmc_cmd: sdmmc_read_sectors_dma: sdmmc_send_cmd returned 0x107
E (9537) diskio_sdmmc: sdmmc_read_blocks failed (263)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're following [This Tutorial](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-cam-take-photo-save-microsd-card/), then you probably got some other problems that came from trying to make that code repeatable, instead of a one use only.
I was able to solve it by directly removing all lines referencing turning off the LED, since it turns off on its own once you stop taking and saving the picture.
At the end of the function you should have something like this:

```
void takePicture(){
  
  //take picture
  camera_fb_t *pic = esp_camera_fb_get();
  if (!pic){
    Serial.println("Error when taking picture");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("Picture taken!");
  //save Pic on SD Card
  EEPROM.begin(EEPROM_SIZE);
  pictureNumber=EEPROM.read(0) + 1;
  String pic_name = "/picture_"+String(pictureNumber)+".jpg";
  fs::FS &fs = SD_MMC;
  Serial.printf("%s: %d bytes\n", pic_name.c_str(), pic->len);

  File pic_file = fs.open(pic_name.c_str(), FILE_WRITE);
  if (!pic_file){
    Serial.println("Error when opening the file");
    return;
  }
  pic_file.write(pic->buf, pic->len);
  Serial.println("Saved file");
  EEPROM.write(0, pictureNumber);
  EEPROM.commit();
  pic_file.close();
  esp_camera_fb_return(pic);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Plase show your whole code, I think you are shutting down the led using GPIO4 before your loop ends.
In my case in a similar case the solution was to add this line before the SD card init:  rtc_gpio_hold_dis(GPIO_NUM_4);